# What the meaning of $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

> $A\in \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{R})$, where $A$ is a matrix.

Thanks for your help. I try google it but found nothing.
If it is not hard for you, explain please the definition of this notation.

Comment: It might be that $Mat_n(R)$ stands for $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, that is, the set of $n\times n$ matrices with real entries.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri  $Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$, the set of $n\times n$ matrices, and $\mathbb{R}^{n^2} $, are not identical spaces. They are isomorphic as vector spaces, but they are different.

Comment: $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is not the same as $\Bbb R^{n^2}$ as I've learned it. The former refers to $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\Bbb R$ while the latter refers to vectors with $n^2$ entries in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

$\text{Mat}_n(R)$ stands for all square matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ as seen in "[Linear Time-Varying Systems: Algebraic-Analytic Approach](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642197260)".

[image]

So $\mathbf A \in \text{Mat}_n(R)$ is simply another way of denoting $\mathbf A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Similarly, $\mathbf A \in \text{Mat}_{\infty}(R)$ would be a $\infty \times \infty$ dimensional matrix.

$$
\mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & ... \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & ...  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
\end{bmatrix}
$$